# Stochastic Differential Equation and Runge-Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations, python, runge-kutta-methods

I have to solve the Black-Scholes equation,

$\textrm{d}X\left(t\right)=\lambda X\left(t\right)\textrm{d}t+\mu X\left(t\right)\textrm{d}W\left(t\right),$

by making use of a RK method (in Python). Since this equation is analytically solvable, I could compare both solutions eventually.

Nonetheless, I would like to encounter a 4th order RK method that could solve this equation rightly (i.e., in comparison to the analytical solution). This is because I will have to use this method to solve deterministic equations as well.

Incidentally, I've already tried to code several RK methods such as this one: [4th order Runge-Kutta Scheme for Stochastic Differential Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622860/4th-order-runge-kutta-scheme-for-stochastic-differential-equations) (the classic one) or the 3/8 method. Both however give solutions that don't agree with the analytical one whatsoever.

Comment: You will already have problems encoding a second order method. Note that the Milstein method still is order 1, Euler-Maruyama could be considered order 0.5. The stochastic increments become more and more complicated.

Comment: For similar questions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576905/115115 with a book reference in the comments. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2339579/115115 references an alternative implementation of the Milstein method, the linked wikipedia article has references to systematic attempts to develop higher order methods.

Comment: Then there must be a way to solve that equation and get a code that can also be used to solve a deterministic one. I heard about a 'Rosenbrock integrator method' but I can't find info about it. Thanks for your time btw :)